# Postgers problem when function calling another function

Tags: postgresql, function, query-optimization, postgis, plpgsql

I am using postgres and I have plpgsql function. In this function, I"m calling another plpgsql function that I wrote. 
But when I'm executing the function it takes a lot of time (around 30 sec). 
When I try to insert the external function content to the first one it's improved the performance significantly to 1 sec and lower. 
Does anyone know why this is happening? 
In this case, the problem solved but I have a similar case with an external function that I can’t insert its content to the first function because this is a longer function.


Code example: 
the implementation that took 30 sec:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f1(arr integer[])
    RETURNS bytea
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    
AS $BODY$
declare
res bytea;
Begin
WITH mvtgeom AS (
SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t.geom, 3857), table2.geom) AS geom, public.f2(t.id ,arr) AS func_res
FROM table1 t, table2
 WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geom, ST_Transform(table2.geom, 4326))
)
    
    SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom, 'public. f1')
    FROM mvtgeom
    INTO res
    RETURN res;
end;
$BODY$;



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f2(idd integer ,arr integer[])
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
declare
result integer;

BEGIN
    IF ARRAY[idd] <@ arr THEN
        result :=0;
    ELSE
        SELECT col1 FRIM table1 t WHERE t.id = idd INTO result;
    END IF;

    RETURN result;
END;
$BODY$;
```

the faster implementation :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f1(arr integer[])
    RETURNS bytea
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    
AS $BODY$
declare
res bytea;
Begin
WITH mvtgeom AS (
      SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t.geom, 3857), table2.geom) AS geom, CASE WHEN ARRAY[t.id] <@ arr THEN 0 ELSE t.col1 END AS func_res
FROM table1 t, table2
 WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geom, ST_Transform(table2.geom, 4326))
)
    
    SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom, 'public. f1')
    FROM mvtgeom
    INTO res
    RETURN res;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually is not good idea to wrap simple SQL queries to functions. Function is black box for optimization, and when you use SQL inside function inside some complex query, then optimizer does optimization of 2 independent queries instead one.

You can create functions in SQL language. These functions are (in some cases) inlined, and then optimizer can do optimization of one query.

If you need to write function in PL/pgSQL language, then is good to use correct flag of your function. When result function depends on arguments, then function should be `immutable`, when function only reads from database, then function should be `stable`. In other cases the function should be marked as `volatile`. This is default. Your function `f2` should be `stable`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f2(idd integer ,arr integer[])
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
...
$BODY$ STABLE;
```

Comment: thank you for responding, but the STABLE flag doesn't improve the performance.
As I said in the question I have a similar case with a different funcion, but in this case, the function is a bit more complex that can't insert into the origin function.
Can it be something that involve stack or memory config?

Comment: @Yoad - probably not - there is high overhead of start nested query